# Power window slows in cold temperatures

Tags: power-windows, cold-weather

My 2001 Sequoia's electronics are still working great. But when it's really cold (20 degrees or less), the driver's side power window is really slow to go up and down. In warmer weather it works fine. Could something be going out?

Comment: It could be that the motor is getting "weak" but more likely there is debris mixed with some old lube in the mechanism that is binding up when it's cold.  You might open up the door panel and see if you can clean things up and make it work better.

Comment: That could very well be a possibility, as I live on and primarily drive dirt roads. I'll give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: Just the driver's side or all windows?

Comment: As a workaround while you can get to looking at it, if you don't open your window much in cold weather, feel free to reach out your hand and grip the top of the glass, pulling the window up to give the motor a help.. Release it near the top, of course :)